# What does the equivalence operator mean when used in a numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, logical-operators, numpy-ndarray

I am following an example which I found it in the **Python Data science handbook** , the purpose of this example is to create two array masks to finally output the *rainy* days in *summer*, the author supposed that summer starts on 21st June which is the 172th day and it ends 3 months later.

Here I am only interested in only the piece of code where he made the summer interval:

```
# Construct a mask for all summer days (June 21st is the 172nd day)
summer = (np.arange((365) - 172 < 90 ) & np.arange((365) - 172 > 0)
```

In another version of the book, I found this code, and I think it leads to the same result:

```
# construct a mask of all summer days (June 21st is the 172nd day)
days = np.arange(365)
summer = (days > 172) & (days < 262)
```

Both examples are not clear to me, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a simple example would help to understand it better.

```
# sample array
In [19]: week = np.arange(1, 8)

# find middle 3 days of the week
# to do so, we first find boolean masks by performing
# (week > 2) which performs element-wise comparison, so does (week < 6)
# then we simply do a `logical_and` on these two boolean masks
In [20]: middle = (week > 2) & (week < 6)

In [21]: middle
Out[21]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False])

# index into the original array to get the days
In [22]: week[middle]
Out[22]: array([3, 4, 5])
```

---

the `&` operator is equivalent to [`numpy.logical_and()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) whereas the `>` and `<` operators are equivalent to [`numpy.greater()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.greater.html) and [`numpy.less`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.less.html#numpy.less) respectively.

```
# create a boolean mask (for days greater than 2)
In [23]: week > 2
Out[23]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])

# create a boolean mask (for days less than 6)
In [24]: week < 6
Out[24]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False])

# perform a `logical_and`; note that this is exactly same as `middle`
In [25]: np.logical_and((week > 2), (week < 6))
Out[25]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False])

In [26]: mid = np.logical_and((week > 2), (week < 6))

# sanity check again
In [27]: week[mid]
Out[27]: array([3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the first part is still not clear for me.